# prove or disprove equivalence of $\alpha$ tautology and $\{\gamma,\alpha\} \Longrightarrow \beta \leftrightarrow \{\gamma\} \Longrightarrow \beta$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I need to prove of disprove that the following 2 propositions are equivalent

1. $\alpha$ is tautology
2. $\{\gamma,\alpha\} \Longrightarrow \beta \leftrightarrow \{\gamma\} \Longrightarrow \beta$

I thought these propositions aren't equivalent because for every $\alpha$ such that $\gamma \Longrightarrow \alpha$, $\{\gamma,\alpha\} \Longrightarrow \beta \leftrightarrow \{\gamma\} \Longrightarrow \beta$ is true but $\alpha$ isn't necessarily a tautology, for example if $\alpha$ is a proposition such that for every model $M$ if $M\models \gamma$ then $M\models \alpha$ else $M\nvDash \alpha$, (2) is true but $\alpha$ isn't a tautology.

But I was told my answer is incorrect due to false assumptions on $\alpha$ but I don't see it is wrong nor where did I assume anything about $\alpha$

Comment: Are you using ⟹ in the same that $\vdash$ gets used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint*

The two conditions are equivalent.

For one side, if $\alpha$ is a tautology, that means that $\alpha$ is always true.

Thus, the cases when $\{ γ,α \}$ is satisfied are exactly the cases when $\{ γ \}$ is.

Similar for the other part.

Comment: Given that there exist no other axioms then what comes in the set on the left-hand side of $\vdash$, {CpCqp, CCpCqrCCpqCpr} $\vdash$ CCpqCCqrCpr is true.  But, {CpCqp} $\vdash$ CCpqCCqrCpr is NOT true.  But, maybe I don't understand the ⟹ notation here, or there exist some assumption about having a complete axiom set here.